# Disable Number field based on selection in dropdown via Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

What I want to do is if a user selects "bycrypt", it should show a field to ask how many passes, and if he/she selects "sha512" to show the same field,but disabled. I was recommended to do this using Jquery,but my attempt is not working.
My code is as follows:

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Security</legend>
    <label>Hash Type</label>
    <select name="hash" id="myId">
            <option value="bcrypt"<?php if($hash == 'bcrypt') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Bcrypt</option>
            <option value="sha512"<?php if($hash == 'sha512') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>SHA512</option>
        </select>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" /></script>
    <label>Bcrypt rounds <i>(12 Rounds is recommended)</i></label>
    <script type="text/javascript>
    $("#myId").change(function() {
var tst = document.getElementById('myId').value;

if (tst ==1) {
    document.getElementById('#bcrypt_rounds').disabled=true;
} else {
    document.getElementById('#bcrypt_rounds').disabled=false;
}
});

    </script>
<input name="bcrypt_rounds" id="bcrypt_rounds" type="text" value="<?php echo $bcrypt_rounds; ?       >" />
```

Updated above. Now cuts the page off after the "bycrpt_rounds" label. Does not get to the field for "bycrypt_rounds".

Comment: Can you show us your `toBuff()` function ?

Comment: @Aelios I was looking around SO for help on this, and saw a couple people use that function. I figured it was a Javascript function (built in, like document.write but specifically for code).

Comment: I'm afraid it is not a build in function from Javascript

Comment: @Aelios Ok, so all I am trying to do there is write some HTML to the the page. I could change to document.write()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myId").change(function() {
    var tst = document.getElementById('myId').value;

    if(tst == "sha512") {
        document.getElementById('number_field_id').disabled=true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('number_field_id').disabled=false;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sweet. Found the `"` that was missing in my script declaration. Quick question, is there a way to also change the value of the disabled field. Right now, I default the fields value to 12, but when it becomes disabled, I'd like to change that to "disabled" or something.

Comment: `$('#bcrypt_rounds').val("disabled")`

Comment: @chriscct7: You should see comments on my question and you should find your answer earlier...

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do

```
$("#myId").change(function() { 
    if($(this).val() == 'sha512'){
      $('#textBxId').attr({'disabled','disabled'});
    }else{
      $('#textBxId').removeAttr({'disabled'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

find the error, you just forget an `"` in `<script type="text/javascript">`

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Security</legend>
    <label>Hash Type</label>
    <select name="hash" id="myId">
            <option value="bcrypt"<?php if($hash == 'bcrypt') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Bcrypt</option>
            <option value="sha512"<?php if($hash == 'sha512') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>SHA512</option>
        </select>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" /></script>
    <label>Bcrypt rounds <i>(12 Rounds is recommended)</i></label>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myId").change(function() {
var tst = $('myId').val();

if (tst ==1) {
    $('#bcrypt_rounds').attr('disabled','disabled');
} else {
    $('#bcrypt_rounds').removeAttr('disabled');
}
});

    </script>
<input name="bcrypt_rounds" id="bcrypt_rounds" type="text" value="<?php echo $bcrypt_rounds; ?       >" />
```

Comment: Doesn't print the input field.

Comment: No, still cuts off the page, and never gets to writing the field.

Comment: find the error, you just forget an `"` in `<script type="text/javascript">`